# Relation with $F$ distribution and $t$ distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, transformation, sampling

If $X\sim F_{n,n}$ , then show that $$\frac{\sqrt n(\sqrt X-\frac{1}{\sqrt X})}{2}\sim t_n$$